# Display Data From Selected Value On the Select Tag to another Text Field

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, html-select, html-input

I want to call 2 values from database, to be placed on **select "dropdown"** and on **input type text**.

This might be considered as illustration :

[image]

When I select a **vendor ID**, I want attribute of selected value to be shown in **Vendor Name** field.
How I should do?

This is the code that i have to call the value for the  tag :

> **in model :**

```
function getAllGroups(){

   $query = $this->db->query('SELECT idvendor, vendorname FROM tbvendor');


            return $query->result();

            //echo 'Total Results: ' . $query->num_rows();
        }
```

> **in Controller :**

```
public function addshipment(){
        $data['title']= 'Vendor ID';
        $data['groups'] = $this->m_shipment->getAllGroups();
}
```

> **in View :**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Vendor ID:</label>
    <div class="input-group">
       <div class="input-group-addon">
           <i class="fa fa-institution"></i>
       </div>
         <select class="form-control input-box" name="idvendor">
            <?php 

             foreach($groups as $row)
             { 
              echo '<option value="'.$row->idvendor.'">'.$row->idvendor.'</option>';
                }
                ?> 
         </select>
 </div>      
</div>
```

> And this is table on my database

[image]

I'm already succeed to call the idvendor to place it on Select dropdown field, but i still can't get a way to place the vendorname into **input type text** when I select the idvendor.

Hope someone can gimme an answer. 
Thanks

Comment: you need to use ajax for this functionality. on change of the select box vendor id, send value to db to get the attributes

Comment: @Alex isnt there another way easier?

Comment: there are many ways to do many things but this would be  the easiest and the most standard approach

Comment: show your code where you create the dropdown for your vendor id - and name us the fields you want to displayed on vendor name, it looks like u r using bootstrap isn't it ? so jquery is already available, because you'll need that

Comment: @sintakonte yes i am using Jquery

Answer (score 0):

Basically imho this is a pretty simple task - since you've posted no code i'll give you an example

your select box

```
<select name="">
    <option value="" data-vendor-name="your vendor name">Vendor Name</option>
</select>
```

your input field

```
<input type="text" name="data-vendor-name" value="" />
```

and the jquery code

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('option[data-vendor-name]').on('change', function()   {
        $('input[name="data-vendor-name"]').val($(this).attr('data-vendor-name'));
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks sir @sintakonte, but my select tag value is "called" from database. I might try to edit the post. but thanks for participating.

Comment: it helps if you post your view code for your vendor name tooo - because this is exactly what i was talking about.